# Looping through files with a date pattern in name in Linux

Tags: regex, bash, tar, logrotate

I'm trying to use the following to tar any file that has a date appended to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

createDate=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}

for file in $HOME/test/*.log.$createDate ; do
    log=$(basename $file)
    find . -type f | tar -zcvf  $log.tar $log
done
```

This should tar any file with a date appended after the log extension, like `test.log.2020-01-01`. However, I get an error:

```
tar: *.log.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

So, its reading this pattern literally, as a string.  What I need is for it to use the pattern to match any file with that date format, after the log extension.  This will eventually into the postrotate section for a logrotate configuration file, but I need to be sure it works first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this pattern as shell glob pattern:

```
createDate=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

Which is actually a regular expression and not really a shell glob pattern. Your glob matching is **failing** and giving only one result: `*.log.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`

This behavior can be changed by using:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Your script should be modified to this:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for file in $HOME/test/*.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]; do
    log=$(basename "$file")
    find . -type f | tar -zcvf "$log.tar" "$log"
done
```